# How to reuse modules across Python installs?

Tags: python, anaconda, gis, qgis, osgeo

I am trying to import a python (2.7.5) module but I'm not sure if I am going at it in the right way. I usually work in Jupyter Notebook (in a seperate Conda env) to keeps things organized per project. Now I am trying to import a module called otbApplication which are Python bindings for a GIS program called Orfeo Toolbox. The thing is, Orfeo Toolbox (together with QGIS) comes with its own Python install (and subsequent paths) and even its own CMD prompt (assuming you use OSGEO4W). If I use this CMD prompt to start Python and import otbApplication, it works fine. But I want to install more packages and just work within my own 'usual'  environment (Jupyter Notebook) in this case.

How should you normally reuse modules between Python installations?

I already tried placing a .pth txt file containing the path to the module in one of the sys.path locations of a different Python installation but it wouldn't even find it. I tried to force it by hosting a notebook (with the same Python install) in the same folder as the module and then importing it. I got the following error which makes me question if I am going at this the wrong way:

```
Python 2.7.5 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  1 2013, 12:37:52) 
[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import otbApplication
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "otbApplication.py", line 28, in <module>
_otbApplication = swig_import_helper()
File "otbApplication.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_otbApplication', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

This means that forcing the same paths to my new installation is not enough, what am I missing? Apologies for the long story (or the probable butchering of some of the terms).

Kind regards,

Jasper

Comment: Is otbApplication maybe a 32-bit installation? 64-bit Python can't load a 32-bit DLL and the error you most often get is that it isn't there, even when you can see that it is.

Answer (score 2):

You've got the right idea with the .pth file, but in order to get it to work you need to check some prerequisites.  Obviously, the syntax needs to be good (just give the directory locations separated by line breaks).  A common issue is that folks don't put the .pth files in the correct directory (usually though not necessarily \Lib\site-packages).  I bet that if you check these you'll be okay.

**Also: as noted in the comments be aware that 32-bit python isn't going to like a 64-bit DLL and verse-visa, so ensure that you're running the right version of python when you try to access those libs.

Comment: Sorry for the late response but yeah, it turned out that the DLL was indeed expecting a 32-bit installation of Python. After ensuring these prerequisites, the .pth file did the trick. Thanks!